# Unable to access record with Geolocation field populated in Community

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, developer-edition

I am encountering an issue where I am unable to access/render a record (of a custom object) in my customer community whenever the Coordinates field (a custom Geolocation field) is filled in. I receive the following error message:

```
Error message: An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1687240840-685915 (-631731787)
```

A couple of additional notes:

- The Coordinates field is not visible on the layout for Community Users
- The Coordinates field is accessible (FLS) to all users within the community
- When the Coordinates field is blank, I am able to access the record in the community without issue.

Might anyone have any idea about why I am unable to access records where the custom geolocation field is populated within the community?

Comment: Have you opened a case with Salesforce?  Were they able to resolve it?  Did they generate a Known Issue for it?

Comment: @DavidCheng - I've tried, but because I am doing this in my own Dev org, I am not able to open a case with Salesforce.